# Image isn't refreshed on application

Tags: php, image, caching, file-upload

I'm working on a PHP application to store some personal information (including photo). I'm storing the image on a specific folder (let's say myapp/images/people/).

After saving a photo my app is redirected to a page showing the information of the specific person (kind of a profile).

If the photo is saved for the first time (no other photo was previously saved for that person) then the photo is shown in the profile. Everything seems to work at this point.

The problem is when I want to change the photo. When I replace a photo my applications keeps showing the old one. I've checked the server and the old photo is gone, there's only the new one (as I need) but the application doesn't show it.

I guess it's something to do with cache.

I've tried by adding the  html tag with no cache values, I've tried by adding the same values by using the header() PHP function but nothing.
I also tried by using:

```
if(file_exists($imagepath))
{
    unlink($imagepath);
}
```

and similar I've used

```
if(file_exists($imagepath))
{
    unlink($imagepath);
    clearstatcache();
}
```

but also nothing.

Can someone help me with this? Any idea about what's going on? The new photo is in the server, the old one is not but the app keeps showing the previous file.

Comment: Perhaps old photo is stored in browser/app cache. Have you cleared the browser/app cache after changing php-header or adding html meta?

Answer (score 0):

The image is cached in the browser. The best way is to generate a new image name on the server and return the new image in the HTML. Since it is a new image for the browser, it won't get it from the cache and you will see the new image in the application.